# Why does shifting my image end up shrinking the image itself?

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing

I am trying to shift an image of a handwritten digit to its (pixel) center of mass while preserving the image dimensions and filling all empty space with white. I wrote the following function:

```py
import numpy as np

def shift(image : np.ndarray, x : int = 0, y : int = 0, output_shape : tuple = (28, 28), fill_value : float = 255.0, dtype : str = "float32"):

    image_shape = image.shape[:2]
    res = image
    col = np.array([[fill_value]]*image_shape[0])
    row = np.array([fill_value]*image_shape[1])

    if x > 0:
        for i in range(x):
            res = np.hstack((col, res))
            res = np.delete(res, len(res[0]) - 1 - i, 1)
    elif x < 0:
        for i in range(np.abs(x)):
            res = np.hstack((res, col))
            res = np.delete(res, i, 1)
    
    if y > 0:
        for i in range(y):
            res = np.vstack((row, res))
            res = np.delete(res, len(res) - 1 - i, 0)
    elif y < 0:
        for i in range(np.abs(y)):
            res = np.vstack((res, row))
            res = np.delete(res, i, 0)
    
    return res.reshape(output_shape).astype(dtype)
```

However, when I use it, it shifts and resizes my image at the same time:

```py
from keras.util import load_img, img_to_array
import scipy.ndimage as ndi
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,1)
ax = ax.ravel()
img = load_img("7.png", color_mode="grayscale")
img = img_to_array(img).reshape(28, 28).astype("float32")
x, y = ndi.center_of_mass(img)

ax[0].imshow(img, cmap="gray")
ax[0].plot(x, y, "ro")

new_img = shift(img, -int(x), int(y))
ax[1].imshow(new_img, cmap="gray")
ax[1].plot(x, y, "ro")

plt.show()
```

[image: wrong_shift]

What I was expecting was, for instance:

[image]

Hence, the shape of the image is preserved and the pixel values as well. However, as you can see, the image is somehow shrunk. What am I doing wrong?

(I also tried using `cv2.warpAffine` together with `skimage.transform.resize` but it leaves behind a black background and the resolution is also worse)

If anyone needs the image, it's [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plbRw.png).

### Update:

I solved the issue by removing `np.delete` and using NumPy's array slicing instead:

```py
def shift(image : np.ndarray, x : int = 0, y : int = 0, output_shape : tuple = (28, 28), fill_value : float = 255.0, dtype : str = "float32"):

    image_shape = image.shape[:2]
    res = image
    col = np.array([[fill_value]]*image_shape[0])
    row = np.array([fill_value]*image_shape[1])

    if x > 0:
        for _ in range(x):
            res = np.hstack((col, res))
            res = res[:, :-1]
    elif x < 0:
        for _ in range(np.abs(x)):
            res = np.hstack((res, col))
            res = res[:, 1:]
    
    if y > 0:
        for _ in range(y):
            res = np.vstack((row, res))
            res = res[:-1, :]
    elif y < 0:
        for _ in range(np.abs(y)):
            res = np.vstack((res, row))
            res = res[1:, :]
    
    return res.reshape(output_shape).astype(dtype)
```

**Result**:

[image: 7_fixed]

I am not sure why `np.delete` <s>causes the shrinking</s> though.

### Update 2:

Ok. I made a mistake and it's not `np.delete` at fault! The following works as well:

```py
def shift(image : np.ndarray, x : int = 0, y : int = 0, output_shape : tuple = (28, 28), fill_value : float = 255.0, dtype : str = "float32"):

    image_shape = image.shape[:2]
    res = image
    col = np.array([[fill_value]]*image_shape[0])
    row = np.array([fill_value]*image_shape[1])

    if x > 0:
        for _ in range(x):
            res = np.hstack((col, res))
            res = np.delete(res, len(res[0]) - 1, 1)
    elif x < 0:
        for _ in range(np.abs(x)):
            res = np.hstack((res, col))
            res = np.delete(res, 0, 1)
    
    if y > 0:
        for _ in range(y):
            res = np.vstack((row, res))
            res = np.delete(res, len(res) - 1, 0)
    elif y < 0:
        for _ in range(np.abs(y)):
            res = np.vstack((res, row))
            res = np.delete(res, 0, 0)
    
    return res.reshape(output_shape).astype(dtype)
```

Comment: I know nothing of python/numpy, but the first images look like every other column/row was deleted, and then insertions were always on the top or right.

Comment: I know nothing of python/numpy, but wouldn't `for i in range(x): ... np.delete(res, len(res[0]) - 1 - i, 1)` effectively delete once for each x? And you're passing in an x of 30, which causes it to delete column 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, etc? So after shifting, that's every other column?

Comment: @MooingDuck My thought process was that that for a matrix, like `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]`, I would delete the last element of each row in each iteration and prepend a new element to each row. So, for instance, if `x = 2`, I would end up with `[[255, 255, 1], [255, 255, 4]]`. In this case, `len(res[0])-1` would be the last entry of each row, and I subtract `i` to move from right to left along each row. But now that I'm looking at it again, I think I'm deleting further than the last/first column/row each iteration. I think just `len(res)-1`/`len(res[0])-1` was enough.

Comment: Just wanted to say that you can write your own solution as the answer and accept it yourself to close the question. Great job on the question, formatting, and illustration btw. Love that simple illustration, 10/10 wish every question was this well written.

Comment: @mimocha Oh, thank you! For some reason I didn't see the giant blue button below. I'll do just that, and thank you again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

I am going to write this as an answer, so I can mark this question as answered (in a couple of days)!

The `np.delete` function did not have anything wrong going on. I made a mistake, where for each iteration it was deleting the i-th column/row from the end of the list, thus, causing the inconsistencies.

The working code is:

```py
def shift(image : np.ndarray, x : int = 0, y : int = 0, output_shape : tuple = (28, 28), fill_value : float = 255.0, dtype : str = "float32"):

    image_shape = image.shape[:2]
    res = image
    col = np.array([[fill_value]]*image_shape[0])
    row = np.array([fill_value]*image_shape[1])

    if x > 0:
        for _ in range(x):
            res = np.hstack((col, res))
            res = np.delete(res, len(res[0]) - 1, 1)
    elif x < 0:
        for _ in range(np.abs(x)):
            res = np.hstack((res, col))
            res = np.delete(res, 0, 1)
    
    if y > 0:
        for _ in range(y):
            res = np.vstack((row, res))
            res = np.delete(res, len(res) - 1, 0)
    elif y < 0:
        for _ in range(np.abs(y)):
            res = np.vstack((res, row))
            res = np.delete(res, 0, 0)
    
    return res.reshape(output_shape).astype(dtype)
```

**Note**: If you want to use this, you might want to swap how the `x` affects the shifting. In my case, I made it so that if `x > 0`, it goes to the right, and viceversa. Some people might find it more intuitive to emulate the four quadrants of the Cartesian plane. So `x < 0, y < 0` means 3rd quadrant, etc.

### Alternative Solution

You can avoid using `np.delete` completely:

```py
def shift(image : np.ndarray, x : int = 0, y : int = 0, output_shape : tuple = (28, 28), fill_value : float = 255.0, dtype : str = "float32"):

    image_shape = image.shape[:2]
    res = image
    col = np.array([[fill_value]]*image_shape[0])
    row = np.array([fill_value]*image_shape[1])

    if x > 0:
        for _ in range(x):
            res = np.hstack((col, res))
            res = res[:, :-1]
    elif x < 0:
        for _ in range(np.abs(x)):
            res = np.hstack((res, col))
            res = res[:, 1:]
    
    if y > 0:
        for _ in range(y):
            res = np.vstack((row, res))
            res = res[:-1, :]
    elif y < 0:
        for _ in range(np.abs(y)):
            res = np.vstack((res, row))
            res = res[1:, :]
    
    return res.reshape(output_shape).astype(dtype)
```